# Django 1.1.1 chokes on multipart/form-data

Tags: python, django, file-upload

## Initial story

I'm trying to implement file upload using a simple form (I'm pasting stripped version, but all important parts are included):

```
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="up_file" size="50">
      <input type="hidden" name="cpk" value="{{c.pk}}">
      <input type="submit" name="btn_submit">
  </form>
```

Now, server-side script running under wsgi was receiving <strike>strange values for "cpk" field and `request.FILES` was empty</strike> empty **request.FILES** and **request.POST** dictionaries, so I decided to switch to development server for debugging.

Surprisingly, ipdb debugger hangs after typing both **request.POST** and **request.FILES** and pressing enter... On the other hand, when I remove *enctype="multipart/form-data"* from  tag, I'm able to check both **request.POST** and **request.FILES**, but of course **request.FILES** is empty then.

(Also wsgi version seems to be healed by removal of *enctype="multipart/form-data"*...)

## Update

I tried all combinations of Opera 10//Firefox 3.5, enctype="multipart/form-data"//no multipart/form-data and dev server//mod_wsgi. **The result is that it's *enctype="multipart/form-data"* that breaks the show**. So now I'm going to check Django bugtracker if it's a known issue.

Meantime, maybe someone here can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to provide your view and form code as we use form uploads with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in Django 1.1.1 with great success.

The following dummy app, for example, works perfectly in the dev server.

**views.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    cpk = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    f = forms.FileField()

def my_upload_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "Got cpk",form.cleaned_data['cpk']
            print "Got file",request.FILES['f'].read()
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form':form})
```

**upload.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {{ form.f }}
        {{ form.cpk }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the django form instance to render the file input, but it renders the very common `<input type="file" name="f" id="id_f" />`.

Using this sample, I get the content of the file (I've tested using a simple text file) printed to the terminal from my dev server. The few gotchas and tests I can recommend are:

- ensure that the file you are uploading is less than `settings.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` (the default is 2.5 MB)
- double-check that you haven't defined any custom file upload handlers that may be breaking the upload process (`settings.FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS`)
- try uploading a very simple file (like a small text file) to see if the issue still persists with something basic
- use a tool to inspect the raw HTTP request/response traffic (firebug will do this for you, and there are some stand-alone apps that will act as a proxy to help you here too)... sometimes the solution will jump out when you can see the raw traffic.

In case you haven't found them yet, the [django file upload docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) have a fair number of examples.

Comment: I've just tried you dummy app - it stucks if pasted into my project, but works perfectly if run as standalone project! That explains all those anomalies, I haven't even suspected that I might be breaking Django request processing at some point. Thank you!